# Apache mod_wl2.4 plugin error parseJVMID

Tags: linux, apache, weblogic, apache-modules, server-administration

I have some issues with setting an clustered environment for weblogic and Apache. The structure is like this: 1 webserver that proxies requests to a clustered environment of 3 weblogic servers.

Everytime i send the request to the apache server , the request gets unhandled. I figured out a part of the problem , but that is something that is not intended in production. whenever i add *DynamicServerList On* the requests fail. When i switch it to off it works, but that means whenever a server fails , apache will still send requests to that server and user experience would be 0.

**EDIT 1:** I am using weblogic 12c and apache2.4 for Centos 7

**EDIT 2:** There is no firewall nor selinux active

Here is my config file for weblogic plugin:

```
 <VirtualHost *:8080>

         ServerAdmin postmaster@webserver2
 
         ServerName webserver2
         DocumentRoot /var/www/webserver2/htdocs
         ErrorLog /var/log/httpd//webserver-error_log
         CustomLog /var/log/httpd/webserver-access_log forwarded
         <Directory />
                 AllowOverride all
                 Order allow,deny
                 Allow from all
         </Directory>
         DirectoryIndex index.html

        <Location />
        SetHandler weblogic-handler
        </Location>
 
 
 
 <IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
             WeblogicCluster 192.168.166.70:8001,192.168.166.71:8001,192.168.166.69:8001
         ConnectTimeoutSecs 15
         ConnectRetrySecs 10
         WLIOTimeoutSecs 600
         DynamicServerList ON
         Idempotent ON
         FileCaching ON
         KeepAliveSecs 60
         KeepAliveEnabled ON
         DebugConfigInfo ON 
        </IfModule>
 
 </VirtualHost>
```

And the errors I get are the following:

> [Mon Sep 14 09:54:58.480616 2015] [weblogic:error] [pid 15343:tid
> 140547949991680] [client 172.18.132.50:57991] <1534314422136982>
> parseJVMID: could not resolve hostname '-1062689209'. Returning NULL
> from parseJVMID
>
> [Mon Sep 14 09:54:58.480681 2015] [weblogic:error]
> [pid 15343:tid 140547949991680] [client 172.18.132.50:57991]
> <1534314422136982> initJVMID: parseClusterServerList failure
>
> [Mon Sep
> 14 09:55:28.481215 2015] [weblogic:error] [pid 15343:tid
> 140547949991680] [client 172.18.132.50:57991] <1534314422136982>
> request [/clusterjsp/HaJsp.jsp] did NOT process
> successfully..................

Comment: Have you checked an answer like: http://middlewaretimes.blogspot.com/2014/03/apache-plugin-got-error-could-not.html ?? The fact that your error says the hostname is `'-1062689209'` seems like the problem

Comment: Yes , i checked all the results for my error and none of them were helpful. I have set up everything as it was recommended and still , it does not work. Wouldn't have posted if I didn't see it as a last resort action

Comment: In your `config.xml` what do your `listen-address` look like for the server and machine? What about the cluster listen-address ?